# How to save a Int value as Double in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

The project is 2 parts, 1 is NodeJS, 1 is Java. NodeJS is using mongoose, and I know in JavaScript and mongoose doesn't have `int` or `float` or `double` type, but Java does. It's a conflict of 2 technicals.

```
{
  number: {
    type: Number,
  }
}
```

I also try using `@mongoosejs/double` module. but it isn't working totally. When I save `number = 1` it still saves the number as `int32`.

Another way: add 6 or 7 zero numbers after the decimal dot to force mongo to save it as double, but have a problem is when number is 0, it save `number: 1e-7`

Comment: I think, with Number only you can store decimal values too.

Comment: @PankajTanwar I know, but when you save an Integer number, mongo saves it as Int32, not Double. I want the field number to always be Double type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mongoose schema you can install using `npm I @mongoosejs/double` in your project directory where node_modules folder is installed. Then in your model where you have defined your schema require on top `const Double = require("@mongoosejs/double");`, and finally in the schema object

```
{
   number: {
      type: Double
   }
}
```

This should be able to save your type as Double in MongoDB. Here is a very useful resource https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mongoosejs/double